# Count values left in Array

Tags: php, arrays, count, sum

I need to figure out how to get the remaining values left in an Array.

Example: I have an array that randomly get two values. I want to get how many are left in that array after removing it.

If i remove 5 values from the array, and have a total of 20 return value 15.

**Edit:** If i have 52 cards in a deck, I draw 2 cards I have 50. If I draw two more cards i have 48.

I need to track how many "cards" are in the dealers array.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$deck = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
unset($deck[0]);
unset($deck[1]);
echo count($deck);
```

unset removes the elements from the array count should be 8 afterwards.
See it work: https://eval.in/163527

Edit:

...and remember arrays are 0 based so your first key unless otherwise defined will be 0. But the count() function will tell you the actual number of elements in the array. So $deck[count($deck)]; would be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This will echo size of array yourarray

```
<?php
echo(sizeof($yourarray));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your array size using a count method such as `count` or `sizeof` store it in a variable and perform logical checks on it? i.e `if()`.. etc . Your question is a tad bit broad.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you make use of the PHP `count` function.

`echo count($yourArray);`

Should do the trick.